# UILabel text truncatingtail dots color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` with `textColor` set to *white*. However, the truncation at the end of the label is still *black*.

I don't have reputation to post image so [here is a link](http://postimg.org/image/qe8j71m8b/). Sorry in advance if the link doesn't work.

I am using `UICollectionView` and the text is `UILabel`, here is my code for the label:

```
    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, 4.0f, 135.0f, 36.0f)];
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    nameLabel.text = _name;
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:15.0f];
    [nameLabel sizeToFit];
    nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [purpleMask addSubview:nameLabel];
```

Has anyone ran into this kind of issue?

Comment: This is a bug in IOS 7 and it comes only if you call sizeToFit method and numberOfLines are greater then 1. You Can set large frame size to avoid this bug.

Comment: Have you tried to add the same label other than collection view ? It doesn't seems to be a truncation dots since they were aligned at the bottom line.

Comment: I guess it is a bug in the system. When I commented out `sizeToFit` the truncation dots changed color liked its supposed to. However the reason I added `sizeToFit` in the first place is because I want to keep the text on the top line if there's only one line of text.

Comment: I just ran into this issue myself. I found out that by setting the label to have a minimum font size 1pt smaller than my desired size, the issue went away. This doesn't seem like a real "solution" for this, but it worked for me and may work for others.

Answer (score 2):

add something like this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Presenting the great..."];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0] range:NSMakeRange(24, 11)];

        nameLabel.attributedText =  string;
```

Answer (score 1):

its working if you use

```
   UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 140.0f, 135.0f, 36.0f)];
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
//nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
nameLabel.text = @"xiusd fdhsf kdsfhkdhskf ih khkh khk fdg dfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfsgdf fdg dfs gdf df fg gdfdfs gdgdfg d gdfg ds  hk hkh kh khk hk hk h";
nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:15.0f];
[nameLabel sizeToFit];
[nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
//nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
```

Comment: This must have been a comment, otherwise please explain how it solves the problem.

Comment: UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 140.0f, 135.0f, 36.0f)];
    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    nameLabel.text = @"xiusd fdhsf kdsfhkdhskf ih khkh khk fdg dfgdf dfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfgdfsgdf fdg dfs gdf df fg gdfdfs gdgdfg d gdfg ds  hk hkh kh khk hk hk h";
    nameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Medium" size:15.0f];
    [nameLabel sizeToFit];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:nameLabel];
i have tried this on my side working fine

Comment: sorry code is too long so it cant be clarify here i have change in answer